# Not enough memory to run HAXM on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, virtualization, haxm

[image: HAXM issue]

Recently I installed Ubuntu instead of Windows and now I was trying to run an android emulator when I faced this issue.
I have 16 GB of RAM of which more than 9 are available. I've already installed kvm and virtualization is enabled in BIOS and my processor supports it. I'd like to get your help and really grateful for any help I can get

Comment: If I remember correctly on windows the HAXM installer asks how much RAM HAXM should be configured to be able to use. Most likely this setting is too small on your system.

Comment: @Robert I remember that option too, but in Ubuntu I have not seen it, unfortunately. All I can do is to change memory settings through Help -> Change memory settings. I set that value to 4096 but still get the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug by switching from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Android studio seems to integrate a version of java that is buggy in its available RAM space on Linux.

This leads to the following error HAXM:
"Device Manager" :
not engough memory to run HAXM
Get more available memory for HAXM

The solution we found to "work around" this problem is to install the java 12 version manually instead of the java 11 version that is provided.

For that download the java 12 version available and put inside your android-studio.

Next, Modify the **studio.sh** file as follows:

add the line :

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate a JDK installation directory command -v will be used to run the IDE.
# Try (in order): $STUDIO_JDK, .../studio.jdk, .../jbr[-x86], $JDK_HOME, $JAVA_HOME, "java" in $PATH.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

STUDIO_JDK="/path/to/android-studio/jdk-12"
```

Comment: To be honest, this is no longer relevant to me but I am grateful for your help anyway